# Synaptic Package Manager keeps crashing

Tags: 11.10, synaptic

Synaptic keeps crashing.
When I open it, it asks for the sudo password.
I give the password, then the synaptic window flashes for less than a second and then goes away.

What's wrong?

After seeing this problem I uninstalled synaptic using apt-get.
Uninstalled, cleaned, removed,  auto-removed,  purged...  every possible option from apt-get.

Then I tried installing synaptic from scratch. Still no luck.

Help please! I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 11.10 yesterday.

I also removed the ~/.synaptic folder -- no luck.

Here is the terminal output:

```
$ sudo synaptic
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
```

Comment: I have the same problem and have yet no idea why it happens, might be a bug from a recent update. But i have a workaround for you: if you open it with "sudo synaptic", at least for me it works.

Comment: hey @Dominik, i have added my sudo synaptic output of the terminal in the edit....... no luck.

Comment: solve it.... posted the answer the question update ... check it out

Comment: Do not post the answer IN the question put it as A proper Answer below!.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Solved it

from this link in [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11343209&postcount=10). In the post, [Jsonwco](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=761340) writes:

> It appears that it's related to **accessibility settings**. I was able to
>   fix this problem on my system by opening Universal Access, **enabling
>   then disabling the screen reader**, then opening Synaptic again.

Comment: Toggling the on-screen keyboard under accessibility settings worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: thanks just solved my problem, hope developers clear this bug..

Comment: The problem prevails in Ubuntu 18.0.4 and the screen-reader on/off option does not work!!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility false
```

It worked for me.

Comment: yup....... this link follows to the answer in the bug discussion of Synaptic at launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/synaptic/+bug/607605/comments/6