# Why does the Synaptic package manager exit when it starts?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synaptic Package Manager keeps crashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69474/synaptic-package-manager-keeps-crashing)

My problem is that whenever I start synaptic package manager from either the terminal or the desktop it starts up and then instantly crashes back to the desktop. I have uninstalled and re-installed but there is no change. I don't know how to fix the broken packages since it is gone from the recovery mode.

If it helps I am running a dell dimension 2350 2.4 GHz CPU, ATI radion x1300 graphics card, 2 GB of ram, and a 13.9 GB hard drive with Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: When you run it from the terminal, does it give any output or errors on the terminal? If so, include that here. That might help in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: This is the error (synaptic:1937): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(synaptic:1937): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(synaptic:1937): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(synaptic:1937): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Answer (score 0):

I just reformatted it's all good now. I have been meaning to do this anyway.

Comment: It happend after i installed America's army. There was an error and it messed alot of things up. But thanks for your answer.