# Cannot open Synaptic

Tags: 11.10, synaptic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synaptic Package Manager keeps crashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69474/synaptic-package-manager-keeps-crashing)

I installed Unity 5 in Ubuntu 11.10, as seen in [OMG!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-install-unity-5-0-in-ubuntu-11-10/) but since then Synaptic is not working. I even tried purging it and reinstalling it again, but it didn't work.

I need to run Synaptic or delete Unity 5. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synaptic has been [known to be susceptible](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/839219) to accessibility settings. You can fix the problem by opening *Universal access* and then disabling the screen reader. If the screen reader is already disabled, then enabling it and then disabling it once again will fix the problem.

Alternatively, you can run the following command in a terminal to fix the problem:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility false
```

Comment: Jokerdino thank you very much, the command resolved my problem with synaptic. :D